# Spring Security 3: Multiple login pages

Tags: spring-security

I need to make two login pages for two roles of users. How to do that in Spring + Spring Security 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint` (perhaps subclassing `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`).   Then set that on the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` using the [`postProcessAfterInitialization` technique](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-namespace-post-processor).